# Merge block for Github Pull request | Expected — Waiting for status to be reported

Tags: github, git-merge, pull-request, git-pull, merge-conflict-resolution

Merging local changes to master are block as it is showing some `Expected — Waiting for status to be reported` error on `Build`.

[Screenshot for merge block error on build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp8jk.png)

Comment: There's a build step that needs to be completed before the PR can be merged. This is something that the repo maintainer set up. You likely just need to wait for the build to finish, but if you provide a link to the PR we can take a closer look.

Comment: I resolved this issue by a blank commit.

Comment: I see. That’s one way to re-run the build.